# C++ namespace variable cannot be accessed without using scope operator

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am having trouble understanding namespaces. A.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A { int pause = 8; }
int main() {
    std::cout << A::pause << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it prints `8`. However, now I add `using namespace A` and change `A::pause` to just `pause`. A.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A { int pause = 8; }
using namespace A;
int main() {
    std::cout << pause << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I get the compile errors:

```
A.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
A.cpp:5: error: reference to ‘pause’ is ambiguous
/usr/include/unistd.h:507: error: candidates are: int pause()
A.cpp:2: error:                 int A::pause
A.cpp:5: error: reference to ‘pause’ is ambiguous
/usr/include/unistd.h:507: error: candidates are: int pause()
A.cpp:2: error:                 int A::pause
```

Can someone explain what went wrong? I thought `using namespace A` allows me to omit the `A::`, similarly to how `using namespace std` allows you to omit `std::`. I tried moving the line in `main()`but I get the same error messages. Note, I purposefully chose the variable name `pause` as it apparently conflicts with the `pause()` declared in `iostream`. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It worked when I added `using::pause` in the beginning of `main()`

Comment: I'd call that a bug in your compiler/library. Including `<iostream>` should not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Did you enable all your warnings? You might get the wrong `pause`!

Comment: There's not even a standard function named `pause()`.

Comment: Yet another example of why using directives should be avoided in general...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is telling you what the problem is.  It has two possible routes to resolve `pause` - one is via `A::pause` and the other is via a function `pause()` which is defined in `<unistd.h>` and exists outside any namespace.  The compiler can't decide which to use so you have to help it.

If you chose a less generic name for your variable inside the `A` namespace, e.g. `pause_val`, you could output it without the namespace scoping

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A { int pause_val = 8; }
using namespace A;
int main() {
    std::cout << pause_val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because there is a *system function* named `pause`. If you check the error message more closely you will see it's also defined in the system header `<unistd.h>`.

The system `pause` function is in the global namespace, and when you do `using namespace A` you pull in the symbols from the `A` namespace into the global namespace as well. So now you have two symbols named `pause` in the global namespace, which is what the compiler complains about.

It *might* have worked if you called the function `pause`, as only functions can be called and not integer variables. However, you can use a function as a variable as well (as function pointers) which leads to this conflict.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, after you added the `using` statement there is **more than one** thing named `pause` in the global namespace. That's why `using namespace whatever;` in global scope is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone explain what went wrong? I thought using namespace A allows me to omit the A::, similarly to how using namespace std allows you to omit std::

Yeah, it does, but then you have *all the other things called `pause`* vying for competition, too.

This is why `using namespace` is oft frowned upon.